# Software to fill in an online search form and report results daily

Tags: web-services, search

Looking for something (preferably web-based, OS X otherwise) that can we can set-up with our desired search terms and options and then fill in the search terms as well as select the various associated menu items on a web site's search page and then provide the results in some sort of report, daily or when the results change.

My search has been rather fruitless. All of the page monitoring services that I have found (such as: watchthatpage.com, changedetection.com, followthatpage.com) can only monitor changes at a specific url.

At the moment this is the search form we will need to monitor.
https://ujsportal.pacourts.us/DocketSheets/MDJ.aspx

Comment: Can any of you code? This should be very easy to automate. Failing that, there are a bunch of sites where you can get programming done cheaply (especially by those who do not live in USA or Europe)

Comment: Couldnt open your link so cant confirm, but autohotkey is a very capable automation tool for windows and probably can do what you want. You need to do a bit scripting but doable. If you strictly need an OS X version ( if you cant find a web alternative) i recommend try autohotkey alternatives for OS X. There seems a bınch of this but never tried any of them.

Answer (score -1):

looks like an automation job.

Read about using Selenium Tool. Link: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I'm deleting this because it isn't as high-quality as we prefer here. Please, feel free to post a new answer after you read and incorporate the [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality). You should have some experience using the software. What exactly did you like about it, and what did you not like as much? How does the software match each requirement in the question? Thanks!